# Override meanjs routes without overwriting meanjs code

Tags: meanjs

The meanjs core module provides a default index page for the home state:

```
// Home state routing
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/home.client.view.html'
})
```

I have added my own module `mymod` to the meanjs application. I would like to use my own partial `modules/mymod/client/views/browse.client.view.html`.

How do I do it WITHOUT modifying the `core.client.route.js` file? I always avoid modifying code obtained from frameworks and belive in overriding. What is the recommended approach to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the point of MEANJS. From [MEANJS github page](https://github.com/meanjs/mean):

> MEAN.JS is a full-stack JavaScript open-source solution, which provides **a solid starting point** for MongoDB, Node.js, Express, and AngularJS based applications. The idea is to solve the common issues with connecting those frameworks, build a robust framework to support daily development needs, and help developers use better practices while working with popular JavaScript components.

MEANJS is not a strict platform that will stop working if you change its own code. Of course that there are some code blocks that should not be modified but there are blocks that you can/should modify to avoid clutter in your code as your app grows.

With that said, you can still keep the route as it is:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'modules/core/client/views/home.client.view.html'
     });
```

And in this partial `modules/core/client/views/home.client.view.html`, you can use AngularJS directive [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) and in the `src` put the path for your custom partial `browse.client.view.html`. This way you don't need to modify `core.client.route.js` you just have to modify the partial `modules/core/client/views/home.client.view.html`.